# Multiple function call on html onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

Is there any possibilities to use the `onclick` HTML attribute to call 
more than one jQuery functions

```
onclick="$('#editParentDetailsViews').removeClass('tab selected');$('#editStudentDetailsPopupPnl').hide(); return false;"
```

Here, the first function work properly and the 2nd function not working.

Comment: Why not just use the jQuery way of adding event handlers instead of that ugly inline crap.

Comment: Maybe point to a function that calls the other functions?

Comment: why do you have return false?

Comment: what do you think about this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/26943947/3176270

Comment: You code is valid, just not recommended. The problem will be with your `$('#editStudentDetailsPopupPnl')` selector if that alone is not working.

Comment: Please provide the HTML of the page as well... While the current answers provide examples of ways you *can* do this, they do not explain why your code does not work (it should work).

Comment: @m59: et al... this is not a duplicate of that other question. Not even close. The real issue is unrelated to parameter passing. Why is everyone so quick to jump on the "it's a duplicate" band-wagon? :)

Comment: is not [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26943947/3176270) your accepted answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest you these ways:

1-`addEventListener`:

```
   document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    function1();
    function2();
   });
```

---

2-inline (`onclick`)

```
onClick="function1();function2();"
```

---

3-Jquery Standard click function:

```
 $("button").click(function(){
    //Your functions code here
});
```

---

4-Jquery on:

```
 $('#button').on('click',function(){
   //Your code here
 })
```

You can find more ways...

Comment: Hi.. big thanks for your answer i just look out these answers and test with my system

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use jquery click() listener? Do not mix dom with jquery. Keep it simple.

```
$(yourselector).click(function(){
    //call some funtions
});
```

Comment: Hi.. big thanks for your answer i just look out these answers and test with my system

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="yup">click me</div>
```

js

```
$(function(){ // same as $(document).ready()...
  $('#yup').on('click',function(){
   // call function 1
   // call function 2
   // call function 3
   // ...
  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/66tu5xnf/)

Comment: Hi.. big thanks for your answer i just look out these answers and test with my system

Comment: Care to tell why downvoted?

Comment: Probably down-voted because you did not explain your code and why it would fix the problem, but I have noticed all the answers so far got downvoted *except one*. Hmmmmm :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie i think, all answers are correct and worth an upvote. people are giving their time to help, this is to appreciate. i dont care for points, but just a bad feeling if you try to help and they turn you their back. my solution is pretty much self-explaining btw isnot it..

Comment: @doniyor: While all the answers are correct snippets of code, none explain why the original does not work either (as that should also be valid code). An *answer* addresses the actual problem, which is still unclear. :)