# Calling multiple function on click of a link using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a link and i want to call multiple javascript functions on a button click , but unfortunately only one function gets called while clicking

```js
$('#CustomerName').on('click', function () { 
    Customername = ($(this).text()); 
    load_data(Customername); 
    load_data2(Customername); 
});
function load_data(Customername){ 
  console.log('load_data'); 
} 
function load_data2(Customername){ 
  console.log('load_data2');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="CustomerName">This is the link text.</a>
```

and the link is

```
<li><i class="metismenu-icon pe-7s-rocket"></i>
  <?php
       // perform actions for each file found
       foreach (glob("CustomerConfigFiles/*.json") as $filename) { 
               echo '<a href="#" id ="CustomerName" class="mm-active">
                '.substr(substr($filename,20), 0, -5).'</a>';
       }
    ?>

</li>
```

But when i run this code only one code gets called "load_data" and am getting output like this
[image: console]

[just referred this question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943872/multiple-function-call-on-html-onclick)

but there was no correct output

Comment: Please check your code, because the JS looks perfectly fine, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/908ezpgt/

Comment: and also it will not work to other link because , the first one will be called only, you need to loop your element with each()

Comment: You added <a> inside the loop in php code. HTML element id must unique throughout the dom, Update this accordingly and check it should work

Comment: i looped the content using foreach @Jerson

Comment: in your js code you must use each in every click

Comment: so how can i achieve this as i want seperate link for each and every file in the folder  @HareshMakwana

Comment: You can use class name instead of id and pass data whatever you want in data attribute like echo "<a href='#' class='CustomerName' data-filename='".$filename."'>" and access this inside function like $(this).data('filename') or $(this).attr('data-filename')

Comment: @sreeshasudhev I've moved the JS code into the JS block in your snippet and added a minimal html-block. Code works exactly as expected.

Comment: i didn't get you how should i loop  on which variable or on which  condition , i can't loop based on the number of files in my folder since on click of first filename i need to call all the function @Jerson

Comment: $('.mm-active').on('click', function () {
               Customername = $(this).attr('data-filename') 
               load_data(Customername);
               load_data2(Customername);});                                                                                                     sorry to say but this is not working in my case @HareshMakwana